# Microsoft Visual C++ console window disappearing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to write a simple program, but when i run the program, the console shows u, prints the output and then immediately disappears.  Is there anyway to stop the console window from disappearing? or to make cout print to the output window in the bottom of Microsoft visual studio?

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the last statement of `main()`.

Comment: Since you're in Visual Studio, you can use `Start without debugging` (ctrl+F5) to run without attaching the debugger. This will run your program from a wrapper command prompt, and show 'Press any key to continue' after your program exits. If you want to write to the VS output window, consider using the Win32 `OutputDebugString` function (but not as a replacement for `cout`/`printf`).

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways...
In the beginning of file:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

And where you want to pause, write:

```
_getch();
```

It will wait until you press any button.

Comment: Why suggest completely unportable code?

Comment: Works just as well to do `std::string dummy; cin << dummy;`

Comment: @Mats: Not quite. The `cin` version requires the `Enter` key to be pressed. There is no portable equivalent to `_getch` as far as I know.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I haven't thought about it. You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, if you hit `ctrl-F5` (start without debugging), it will pause after execution, showing `Press any key to continue`.

If you hit `F5` (Start with debugging), the Console window closes immediately after execution.

Comment: I just tried this in Visual Studio Community and it does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either compile in `Debug` and put a breakpoint at the last line of `main()` or add this below your functional code:

```
std::cin.get();
```

This method requires you to include `<iostream>`.